# Firefox mediaquery min-width

Tags: html, css, firefox, media-queries

I'm making a website using HTML5 & CSS3. It needs to be responsive, so I'm making use of mediaqueries. I have set the following:

```
 @media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
     #hamburger {
          display: none;
     }
     #desktop-nav {
         display: inline;
     }
 }
```

It works fine in all browsers, except firefox (latest version). It already executes on 800 & something.

Anyone any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: Probably the problem is somewhere else, this code looks correct.

Comment: What is the (latest) FF version? And what OS?

Comment: @LarsGraubner why does it execute, but only on the wrong width? but on all other browsers (explorer, edge, opera, safari, chrome) it works fine.

Comment: @putvande version 45.0 and windows 10